# Kotlin - Search in nested list

Tags: android, kotlin, filter

My question is about algorithm.

This response is sent from Backend

```
"categoryList": [
      {
        "benefitList": [
          {
            **1**
            "carType": "SEDAN",
          },
          {  
          **2**  
            "carType": "SEDAN", 
          }
        ],

        "title": "Volvo",

      },
      
      {
        "benefitList": [
          {
            **3**
            "carType": "SEDAN",
        
          },
          {
            **4**
            "carType": "HATCHBACK",
          },
              
          
        ],

        "title": "Mercedes",
      
      }
]
```

categoryList -> parentList
benefitList -> nestedList

I want to filter by carType and want to get list like this

```
"categoryList": [
      {
      
        "benefitList": [
          {
            **4**
            "carType": "HATCHBACK",
          },
              
          
        ],
        "title": "Mercedes",
     
      }
]
```

But when I filtering this code like this

```
categoryList.filter { categoryDto ->
            categoryDto.benefitList.any { cardDto ->
                cardDto.authType == HATCHBACK 
            }
        }
```

HATCHBACK item turn correctly but SEDAN comes with HATCHBACK

If I say with numbers, **3** and **4** items are returning.

Is anyone can help me ? I just wanna reach **4** item without **3** ?

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can't solve this problem with simple filtering, etc., because in fact you need to create an entirely new `categoryDto` object (or modify an existing one). You didn't have `categoryDto` with `4`, but without `3` in your original data structure, so you need to create it.

Depending on how your dto is being created, it could be something similar to:

```
categoryList.mapNotNull { categoryDto ->
    val benefitList = categoryDto.benefitList.filter { cardDto ->
        cardDto.authType == HATCHBACK 
    }
    if (benefitList.isEmpty()) null else categoryDto.copy(benefitList = benefitList)
}
```

I wrote above code by hand, I didn't test it, so there may be some mistakes.